# OOM when using NetworkImageView ( of Volley library)

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-volley, networkimageview

### Background

Using the [**Volley library**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo)'s [**NetworkImageView**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) is a convenient way to handle showing images from the web.

However, it has some bugs (as i've written [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875357/volley-networkimageview-sometimes-doesnt-show-the-error-image)).

### the problem

One of the issues that you can have by using it is that it doesn't decode the images from the web in a memory efficient way.

This means that if you use a gridView with multiple NetworkImageView in it, and each shows an image that has an unknown resolution (could be small, could be large), you would end up having an OOM .

as an example, you can set the url of this object to be [**this one**](https://github.com/danleech/simple-icons/diff_blob/d6f771d1e17a292681228d5bcdc624a60a18c93f/icons/android/android-4096.png?raw=true) and see for yourself how much memory the app uses after showing the bitmap, compared to how much it used before.

### The question

How can i modify the way that NetworkImageView decodes the bitmap ?

One way I could change it is to make it decode the bitmap while downscaling it to the needed size (or at least set the max of it to the screen size), for example using [**this method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408505/how-to-downscale-images-correctly) of downscaling .

Answer (score 16):

Volley has a built in method for fitting an image to a given width and height like you mentioned. You need to stop using the convenience methods of loading images provided by `NetworkImageView` which don't use it. I suggest using the following methods to decrease the chance for OOM errors:

1. Stop using `NetworkImageView`. Use a regular `ImageView` and implement the listener to apply the image when it is available. *This is a prerequisite for step 2. Using a `NetworkImageView` with the `get()` method may lead to problems in my experience`.*
2. Create an `ImageLoader` and use the `get()` method which receives an `ImageRequest`. Use the optional constructor that takes in a *maxHeight* and *maxWidth* as parameters if you can.
3. When you use the previously mentioned `get()` method in the `ImageLoader`, save the `ImageContainer` reference that method returns so you'll be able to cancel a request if the view is recycled before the request completes.
4. Provide a good implementation for an `ImageCache` in the `ImageLoader` constructor. That'll lower the redundancy in decoding bitmaps that are already available.
5. If your architecture allows it, try to use the `recycle()` method on the bitmaps, but be careful not to recycle the ones you might still need.

### EDIT: Added Code Samples

Code snippet for (2) + (4)

```
// assuming sRequestQueue is your static global request queue 
// and `BitmapCache` is a good implementation for the `ImageCache` interface
sImageLoader = new ImageLoader(sRequestQueue, new BitmapCache());
```

Code snippet for (3) assuming the *ViewHolder* pattern and `imageContainer` is a member of the `ViewHolder` class. The principal applies to any architecture.

```
// when applying a new view cancel the previous request first

if (imageContainer != null) {
    imageContainer.cancelRequest();
}

// calculate the max height and max width

imageContainer = sImageLoader.get(imageUrl, 
    new DefaultImageListener(image), maxWidth, maxHeight);
```

The default image loader (you can do what you here):

```
private class DefaultImageListener implements ImageListener {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public DefaultImageListener(ImageView view) {
        imageView = view
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //handle errors
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show a sample code ? Also, why did google make this class if it can't handle large images in any good/customized way?

Comment: The `NetworkImageView` is syntactic sugar for loading remote images in a basic way. If you'll listen to the keynote you'll see the Ficus (the lead developer) says that the `NetworkImageView` is basically, and I quote, for "lazy" developers (he means that in a good way). It's a good basic solution, but if you need something specific you'll have to use a different mechanism. I'll edit my answer and put up some samples.

Comment: a lazy developer is usually a good developer, which takes the work of others instead of re-inventing the wheel and waste time on new bugs. this is not the case, since this class isn't good enough for images that could fill the memory. it doesn't even have a way to fix this issue in a custom manner.

Comment: That is not entirely correct, I just posted some custom fixes. Also things are never black and white. You need to take into account that Volley is new, and like all new products it's constantly evolving and expanding.

Comment: have you tested your code on super large images, like the one i've posted about?

Comment: I don't know what "super large" is translated to, but I have tried this with regular sized photos you find on most news sites. You're more than welcome to try it, the image scaling should be fine. In anyway, these are best practices I stand behind.

Comment: "super large" is large enough to make your device go OOM in case you really decode the bitmap in the normal way without any downsampling. i think that if the code handles even those kind of images, it can handle smaller images as well...

Comment: Look at the snippet for (3). There's an example for both the `get()` method and the listener I mentioned on step (1).

Comment: Let's go through what I wrote: *"Use a regular ImageView and implement the listener to apply the image when it is available."* On the step (3) code I wrote: `imageContainer = sImageLoader.get(imageUrl, 
    new DefaultImageListener(image), maxWidth, maxHeight);` Assuming `image` is your `ImageView` that has a reference is stored in the `ViewHolder` class. That covers step (1).

Comment: again , i still don't understand what it means , so i hoped you'd show me via code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37149/discussion-between-itai-hanski-and-android-developer)

Answer (score 3):

I found a better solution in my search : -)

NetworkImageView knows its width at line no - 104 and height at line no - 105 in the link [NetworkImageView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java)

Below is the exact code at [NetworkImageView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java)

```
    private void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
    int width = getWidth(); // at line no 104
    int height = getHeight(); // at line no 105
```

you only need to forward this information to the image loader.

On line 141 [NetworkImageView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) calls the ImageLoader#get(String 
requestUrl, final ImageListener listener) method without width and 
height. Change this call to ImageLoader#get(String requestUrl, 
ImageListener imageListener, int maxWidth, int maxHeight).

**Replace the code from line no 141 to 172 of** [NetworkImageView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) **with below code**

```
ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
            new ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                        setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(final ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    // If this was an immediate response that was delivered inside of a layout
                    // pass do not set the image immediately as it will trigger a requestLayout
                    // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image by posting back to
                    // the main thread.
                    if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                        post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                onResponse(response, false);
                            }
                        });
                        return;
                    }

                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                        setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
                    }
                }
            }, width, height);
```

Comment: can you please show the exact code to put and where to put it (not just line number) ?

Comment: so this fixes the problem? maybe you should write about it on the issues/requests of the github website? sadly i can't test what you've written since i have stopped using this library. maybe some day i will try it out again.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing too! Although, I am unsure of the cached image though... If you start off with a Gridview, and with this code change, does this mean that the cached "image" will be smaller? And when you switch to a "full screen" view, upon clicking the GridView image, will it reuse the low sample image?

Comment: I am not sure that the cached size is small, but when you are setting image to NetworkImageView, it set the small size of image.

Comment: does this prevent all of your Out of Memory errors?