# OutOfMemory error in ImageLoader

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am using ImageLoader and refering [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

I have used both methods `DisplayImages()` and `getBitmap()` but getting `OutOfMemory` error every time. From the developer site I have read and found that it can be solved by using `RecycleImageView` and `RecycleBitmapDrawable` classes.

No idea, how to implement this in adapter's `getView()` methd.

After using `android:largeHeap="true"` , The logcat displays...

```
02-27 13:21:00.846: D/OpenGLRenderer(12301): Enabling debug mode 0
02-27 13:21:03.379: D/dalvikvm(12301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2273K, 18% free 12037K/14580K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 24ms
02-27 13:21:12.028: D/dalvikvm(12301): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 339K, 14% free 12605K/14580K, paused 29ms, total 36ms
02-27 13:21:13.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(12301): Grow heap (frag case) to 152.441MB for 144636048-byte allocation
02-27 13:21:13.240: D/dalvikvm(12301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4352K, 5% free 149498K/155828K, paused 14ms+5ms, total 61ms
02-27 13:21:16.003: D/dalvikvm(12301): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 149498K/155828K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
02-27 13:21:16.003: I/dalvikvm-heap(12301): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 325431088-byte allocation
02-27 13:21:16.043: D/dalvikvm(12301): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 5% free 149488K/155828K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
02-27 13:21:16.043: E/dalvikvm-heap(12301): Out of memory on a 325431088-byte allocation.
02-27 13:21:16.043: I/dalvikvm(12301): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-27 13:21:16.043: I/dalvikvm(12301):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41f7cb50 self=0x41f6c1d0
02-27 13:21:16.043: I/dalvikvm(12301):   | sysTid=12301 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075268828
02-27 13:21:16.043: I/dalvikvm(12301):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=296 stm=68 core=0
02-27 13:21:16.043: I/dalvikvm(12301):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
```

Comment: try using thumbnail, since ur image semms to be too huge

Comment: Please Ref This Link Dude.

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059479/out-of-memory-handle-in-android?noredirect=1#comment33449769_22059479

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795645/exception-outofmemoryerror/21950787#21950787   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043232/out-of-memory-exception-with-custom-gridview/22043466#22043466

Comment: @Monika yes.. i think.. u say correct?

Comment: @Monika No, Images sizes are just 10kb - 20kb and I have already used decodeFile() method to reduce size to half but it's still not working.

Comment: @Android Ref This link also.. this also helpful to you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap

Comment: @saravanan Thanks, But I have already used it, didn't work for me...

Comment: Try this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: File size is not important.  What resolution are the images and how many?  `Out of memory on a 325431088-byte allocation` what are you loading that is trying to take 320MB of memory?

Comment: @Simon I don't know why?, This is the array of image url : **[http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/262_1.jpg, http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/229_1.jpg]**

Comment: @Simon  The second image size is just 13.91kb, width 252, height 166.

Comment: That image on it's own will take 167kb when loaded (width x height x 4 bytes) unless you scale it.  With an array, you could quickly run out of heap space.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your support, I found my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979799/outofmemory-error-in-volley-library/22086617#22086617).

Answer (score 0):

use android:largeHeap="true" in your manifest file in side application tag.

Comment: I have edit my question, the problem is still no solved