# Volly imageLoader onResponse imageContainer width null

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley, image-loading

I'm trying to get image bitmap and redraw it in rounded image . but unfortunately i got NPE on imageContainer [the width is actually NULL].

here is what i have tried so far,

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(ImageContainer image, boolean arg1) {

                    RoundedDrawable rd=new RoundedDrawable(image.getBitmap());
                    holder.image.setImageDrawable(rd);

                }
```

Comment: Is it the ImageContainer that is null or the bitmap?

Comment: the bitmap is null! getting NPE on bitmap.getWidth() Actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the width that is null, it is the bitmap.

You probably want to see this:
[Volley image bitmap is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209114/volley-image-bitmap-is-null/28553767#28553767)

`onResponse()` can and will give you a null bitmap sometimes. In fact, `onResponse()` is called with a null bitmap once whenever the image is not found in the ImageLoader cache.
This call with a null bitmap happens when the ImageLoader starts to fetch a remote image (not in cache).

**This is actually a good thing.**

It allows you to present the user with some kind of wait-while-image-is-loading image or progress bar.

`onResponse()` will be called again later with a non null bitmap if everything goes right.

So really, all you have to do is:

```
public void onResponse(ImageContainer image, boolean arg1) {
    if(image.getBitmap() != null){
       RoundedDrawable rd = new RoundedDrawable(image.getBitmap());
       holder.image.setImageDrawable(rd);
    }
    else
       //set a waiting image or progress bar
}
```