# when the image is attached to NetworkImageview ? volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using `Volley`, for loading image from network I use `NetworkImageview`

I show some scaling animation on the `NetworkImageview`

```
holder.imgPostPic.setImageUrl(model.Uri, imageLoader);   
holder.imgPostPic.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.im_home_no_internet);
```

**my problem**

when I start scaling animation, the DefaultImageResId starts scaling , which I don't want.

**what I want**

I want the animation to start only when the image is loaded to the `NetworkImageview` like `Zomato app` does it.

**my code**

```
imageLoader.get(model.Uri, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                                if (response != null) {
                                        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                                animate1(myBucketListViewHolder, true);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                });
```

**I am always getting `NULL` bitmap with this code**

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209114/volley-image-bitmap-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

With this code before any network call Volley checks for cached bitmap if not it sets a null bitmap container which sets your default image.

> ```
> final String cacheKey = getCacheKey(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType);
>     // Try to look up the request in the cache of remote images.
>             Bitmap cachedBitmap = mCache.getBitmap(cacheKey);
>             if (cachedBitmap != null) {
>                 // Return the cached bitmap.
>                 ImageContainer container = new ImageContainer(cachedBitmap, requestUrl, null, null);
>                 imageListener.onResponse(container, true);
>                 return container;
>             }
>
>             // The bitmap did not exist in the cache, fetch it!
>             ImageContainer imageContainer =
>                     new ImageContainer(null, requestUrl, cacheKey, imageListener);
>
>             // Update the caller to let them know that they should use the default bitmap.
>             imageListener.onResponse(imageContainer, true);
> ```

This is why you have always at least 1 null bitmap response.

However if you have ONLY null for the bitmap then you have some other (possibly network) error which can be checked in your onErrorResponse.