# Volley loads the same thumbnails

Tags: android, caching, thumbnails, android-volley

I have problem with a Volley and a ListView. Maybe I do not understand how Volley should work... Look here, this is code from my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache());

    items = createItemList();

    expListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter();
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

I setup `Volley.newRequestQueue(this)` and `ImageLoader` with `BitmapLruCache` ([the same here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682595/android-volley-imageloader-bitmaplrucache-parameter)).

When in my ListAdapter i override `getView()`

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) 
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
        final ImageView ivCover = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icCoverThumb);
        imageLoader.get(items.get(position).url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(ivCover, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Here i use `imageLoader.get(items.get(position).url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(ivCover, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher));` (is tender spot here?).

Thumbs was loaded but smth went wrong: when app starts first time, the first item in the list view has duplicate ico with one of the icons from the other line - http://prntscr.com/1wmrck

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to reproduce without more information, but I would recommend the use of `NetworkImageView` to load thumbnails from the network and btw, I would use a "ViewHolder" to improve the performance of your `ListView`

This is a sample `ArrayAdapter` to show tweets on a ListView

```
...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tweet_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.twitterUserImage);
        //set more views (username, text, date ...)

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //get the current element from the data array
    Tweet currentTweet = getItem(position);

    //set data into the views
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(currentTweet.getUser().getProfileImageUrl(), VolleyManager.getImageLoader());
    //...


    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private NetworkImageView imageView;
    //other views...
}
```

Comment: i'll check. thef if it will be stil need, i'll add more information. Thanks!

Comment: about viewholder pattern i know, yeah

Comment: Yah! Thank you very much, it works! I've switched ImageView to NetworkImageView and set image as you describe d holder.imageView.setImageUrl(URL, VolleyManager.getImageLoader());