# Cache Images with Volley

Tags: java, android, caching, android-volley

I'm trying to implement Image Caching into my app. The code i currently have regarding the images is below:

Network call to get images:

```
public void getImage(String url, final ImageView imageView) {

    System.out.println("Image Url is: " + url);
    ImageRequest requestImage = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null, null);

    queue.add(requestImage);
}
```

How could I implement the caching? I have read a few articles on SO, but am not sure on how to implement it into my app?

Thanks for your help

Comment: good to past links of articles which you read. so I can suggest you from that

Comment: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21848948/863257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have better use `ImageLoader` instead of using `ImageRequest` directly.
2. When you instantiate an `ImageLoader` object, you set an `ImageCache` object. (That is what you want, isn't it?)

Volley's `ImageLoader` uses internally `ImageRequest` convined with `ImageCache`.

Comment: how to add the image loader in the request ?  if i have the below 
mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
                        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
                        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader); .. it works without a request , do I need a request to cash it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this one of the best image caching library :

https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view