# Android app doesn't show images from Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, apache2

I would like to cache images from the internet.
If I load the image from my raspberry (http://192.168.192.200/QuoteU/images/testcache.jpg) and I have no internet, the app doesn't appear the image. (I loaded it before from the internet). If I load the image from the source (https://fs01.androidpit.info/a/63/0e/android-l-wallpapers-630ea6-h900.jpg), the app appears the image even if the smartphone has  no internet. I am using the ImageLoader-Class from volley and apache as my webservice. It must be a server-problem, am I right?

Volley:

```
if(ImageLoader imageLoader == null){
    imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
}

FeedImageView imageViewQuote = (FeedImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
imageViewQuote.setImageUrl("https://fs01.androidpit.info/a/63/0e/android-l-wallpapers-630ea6-h900.jpg", imageLoader);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added either the volley code or your apache configuration if that's what you're asking about

Comment: The apache configuration is not edited, I just install it with no furhter configurations. Volley code is above.

Comment: I don't think either apache or volley cache by default

Comment: I guess volley is not the problem because from the other server, the image will be cached.

Comment: Volley could be the problem if you didn't setup the cache correctly.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21848948/2308683

Comment: I am using a class that extends LruCache. Like I said, if I retrieve the image from another server, it works but not from my raspberry...

Comment: Can you ping your Raspberry Pi from your android device ? Can you open the image served from your Pi in a web browser, either on android device or on PC ? Do you see any errors in LogCat ?