# How to get Image Bitmap from cache with Volley Library

Tags: android, bitmap, android-volley

I want to get Image from cache memory, I am using volley library and displaying image successfully. I want to get same downloaded image from cache
 Below is my code.

```
Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
Entry entry = cache.get(ImageUrl);
if (entry != null) {
    try {
        // Get Data From Catch Successefully
        String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");

        // but now this code return null value i want Bitmap From Catch
        LruBitmapCache bitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        mBitmap = bitmapCache.getBitmap(data);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can get data from cache, but bitmapCache.getBitmap(data); return's **null**.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396852/volley-image-caching

Comment: I think you have to use Android Query instead of Volley which provide cache functionality easily like simple enable true cache falg get more info from here : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: But I get catch data successfully into  String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8") but problem is that data not convert in to bitmap

Answer (score 2):

use this line instead to convert entry.data into `bitmap`:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entry.data, 0, entry.data.length);
```