# Getting ImageLoader faster in Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an android application, I am getting data from an JSON web services, But the loading of images is too slow even I am using ImageLoader, I want loading of data like `Android application Of YouTube` , It is loading data very fast even on 2G mobile n/w connection.

Pls Help me, how can I do that....

Comment: it depends on lot of things like the image sizes which you download etc,,, try with volley library which is having some optimality and can help you!!

Comment: 1) Profile your app to see where the time is spent 2) Optimize the bottlenecks 3) Repeat

Comment: You can try Picasso library. It's easier to use than Volley and pretty fast and reliable. Check it here - https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest option today is to use **Volley**.

Watch this Google IO talk: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

And here is an example: http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/

Just replace your ImageView by NetworkImageView in your XML like ths:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/networkImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

And in your source code (in your adapter), you set the URL like this:

```
yourNetworkImageViewReference.setImageUrl( "you_url_here" , MyVolley.getImageLoader() );
```

PS: You will also need the BitmapLruCache class you can find on this post: [Android Volley ImageLoader - BitmapLruCache parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682595/android-volley-imageloader-bitmaplrucache-parameter).

Comment: Thanks for your support, I hope that it will help me....

Comment: Thanks, I have read about the volley library, it's really so fast, can you provide me any link from that i can setup volley into my project for loading images

Comment: I've added some code example in the answer, together with the BitmapLryCache class. Make sure to follow the full example provided in the first link.